# How to get configured retryable/skippable exceptions in jsr352

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsr352, jbatch

I'd like to write some generic batch listeners to log out some useful information of all batches configured in my application. To do so I'd like to get the configured skippable/retryable exceptions from batch configuration. However I did not find any API for that. Is there a way to retrieve this configuration independant of the jsr352 implementation?

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you won't see this or anything similar really in the specification API (so anything that did exist would be impl-specific).

The theme of separation of concerns lies behind many of the API choices, and nothing like a "job definition model" API exists in the spec.